# locking stop loss with ATR line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I encounter a problem, I want my stop loss to be a straight line based on ATR at the time of the entry,
but I think the problem is when I'm still in buy (entry) position, the longcondition match and trigger another new stop loss line. Can somebody help me? Thank you so much!

the picture:

[moving stop loss line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JEZj.png)

new stop loss line > BLUE CIRCLE

stop loss line should be like the RED DOTTED LINE

```
//@version=5
strategy("strategy learning", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, commission_value = 0.2, pyramiding = 0)

var GRP0 = "------------------------------ ATR  ------------------------------"

// Input for ATR Period
atrPeriod = input.int(25, "ATR Period", group = GRP0)

// Input for ATR Multiplier
atrMultiplier = input.float(2.0, "ATR Multiplier")

var GRP1 = "------------------------------ EMA  ------------------------------"
// Draw 2 EMA lines.
len1 = input(50, "EMA 1", group =GRP1)
len2 = input(200, "EMA 2", group =GRP1)
ema1 = ta.ema(close, len1)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, len2)
plot(ema1, color=color.yellow, linewidth = 2)
plot(ema2, color=color.blue, linewidth = 2)

// Define ATR Band Upline and Bottomline.
atr = ta.atr(atrPeriod)
bottomline = open - atrMultiplier * atr
atr_risk = atrMultiplier * atr
plot(bottomline, color=color.white)

var GRP2 = "------------------------------ STOCH RSI  ------------------------------"
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1, group = GRP2)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1, group = GRP2)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1, group = GRP2)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1, group = GRP2)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source", group = GRP2)
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
crossup = ta.crossover(k,d)

//condition long
xx = close < ema1
xx2 = close[1] > ema1
xxx = ema1 > ema2
xy = close > ema2
xxy = xx and xxx and xy and xx2
plotshape(xxy, location= location.belowbar, style =shape.triangleup, color=color.green, size=size.normal)

//LONG
// Check if current crossup is higher than previous crossup
prev_k = ta.valuewhen(crossup, k, 1)
prev_d = ta.valuewhen(crossup, d, 1)
crossup_highest = k > prev_k and d > prev_d

longcondition = xxy and crossup_highest

if(longcondition) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=1)

var GRP3 = "--------------------------MULTIPLIER--------------------------"
m = input(3, "take profit multiplier", group = GRP3)
upline = bottomline + m * atr_risk
var float fixedBottonline = 0
var float fixedUpline = 0

if nz(longcondition[1])
    fixedUpline := upline
    fixedBottonline := bottomline
    strategy.exit("exitBuy", "buy", limit=fixedUpline, stop=fixedBottonline)

longEnterPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)

p1 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? fixedUpline : na, color = color.green, style = plot.style_linebr,linewidth = 2, title="Long Profit Line")
p3 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? fixedBottonline : na, color = color.red, style = plot.style_linebr,linewidth = 2, title="Long Stop Loss Line")
p2 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? longEnterPrice : na, color=color.white    , style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 2, title="Long Entry Line")

fill(p1,p2, color= color.new(color.green, 80), title="Long Profit Background")
fill(p2,p3, color= color.new(color.red,   80), title="Short Stoploss Background")
```

Comment: In the code that you post, there is no red line
According to your image, the red line is the one with the problem

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply...

the red line is in this code:

p3 = plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? fixedBottonline : na, color = color.red, style = plot.style_linebr,linewidth = 2, title="Long Stop Loss Line")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the *Limit* and *Stop* value only when you open the position. Not on every candle.

Try *strategy.position_size* and a *ternary*
Something like that:

```
if nz(longcondition[1]) and strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0
    fixedUpline := upline
    fixedBottonline := bottomline
    strategy.exit("exitBuy", "buy", limit=fixedUpline, stop=fixedBottonline)
```